# Angular 1.5 seed for Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm going to create a new Angular 1.58 project using typescript and component. Is there a seed project with best practice for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think http://fountainjs.io/ could be the right thing for you. I had great success with it.

Comment: how does this answer the question at all?

Comment: because it seeds you a project, with if wanted a full todo list example that in my opinion shows a best practice of how to set up an angular app with typscript/es6 syntax like e.g. classes. I don't know why this doesn't answer the question but if you think i got the question wrong i will just delete my answer. Anyway its a 3 month old question.

Comment: I see. Those are all things you should have included in your answer rather than saying it worked for you.